# Element is shown on page as <span class="icon">&#xe80d;</span> rather than being rendered

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have the following ReactJS component:

```
class Menu1item extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.glyph}{this.props.value}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The component is used like below:

```
<Menu1item glyph={menu.glyph1} value={menu.menu1}/>
```

And `menu` is like below:

```
menu={menu1: 'YOU', glyph1: '<span class="icon">&#xe80d;</span>'}
```

The component is rendered like below:

[image]

I wonder how I can actually render the `span` element.

---

Applied the suggested solutions and now it works fine:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing quotes around `'<span class="icon">&#xe80d;</span>'`.

This should do it:

```
const menu = {
  menu1: 'YOU',
  glyph1: (<span class="icon">&#xe80d;</span>)
};
```

**Explanation:**

You are passing a string literal to the glyph prop, so it is literally rendering the string `'<span class="icon">&#xe80d;</span>'`, as expected. If you pass a `<span>` instead, then it should render a `<span>` like you want it.

Remember, you are using JSX, so you can write HTML-style tags without quotes, and they will be compiled to `React.createElement()` calls.

**EDIT:**

Since `class` is a reserved word, React uses the `className` prop instead. So you should actually write

```
const menu = {
  menu1: 'YOU',
  glyph1: (<span className="icon">&#xe80d;</span>)
};
```

Thanks to @novaline for catching this.

Comment: If you do this, you should use `className`, not `class`.

Comment: Or: `webpack.config.js` => `loader: 'babel-loader'` => `query` => `plugins` => `transform-class-properties` then able to use `class` as a prop

Comment: @user7312233 nice!

Answer (score 1):

You need `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`:

```js
render() {
  return (
      <div>
          <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.glyph}}></span>
          {this.props.value}
      </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Why not just remove quotes around the HTML string, and use the JSX syntax? Using dangerouslySetInnerHTML for this scenario is pretty much the equivalent of  abusing `eval()` in Javascript. Like using `var x = eval('{y: "z"}');` instead of the much simpler `var x = {y: "z"};`.